# Union won't take members of type 'string'

Tags: c++, c++11

Whenever I tried to compile this **code**:

```
union foo {
    std::string dunno;
} bar;
```

It gives me this bunch of errors. What's wrong with it?:

```
_foo.cpp:6:3: error: use of deleted function 'foo::foo()'
 } bar;
   ^
_foo.cpp:4:7: note: 'foo::foo()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 union foo {
       ^
_foo.cpp:5:14: error: union member 'foo::dunno' with non-trivial 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]'
  std::string dunno;
              ^
_foo.cpp: In function 'void __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
_foo.cpp:6:3: error: use of deleted function 'foo::~foo()'
 } bar;
   ^
_foo.cpp:4:7: note: 'foo::~foo()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 union foo {
       ^
_foo.cpp:5:14: error: union member 'foo::dunno' with non-trivial 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::~basic_string() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]'
  std::string dunno;
              ^
_foo.cpp: In function 'void __tcf_1()':
_foo.cpp:6:3: error: use of deleted function 'foo::~foo()'
 } bar;
   ^
```

Can you explain, why?

Answer (score 10):

C++11 did indeed introduce the possibility to include arbitrary types in unions. However, you need to give the union all special member functions which those types have. It's nicely summarised in C++11 9.5/2:

> [ *Note:* If any non-static data member of a union has a non-trivial default
>   constructor (12.1), copy constructor (12.8), move constructor (12.8), copy assignment operator (12.8), move
>   assignment operator (12.8), or destructor (12.4), the corresponding member function of the union must be
>   user-provided or it will be implicitly deleted (8.4.3) for the union. *—end note* ]

Which means that if you want your union to have a default constructor, you must define it, something like this:

```
union foo {
    std::string dunno;
    foo() : dunno() {}
} bar;
```

Answer (score 1):

C++03 standard forbids types with non-trivial constructor(`std::string` constructor is non-trivial) to be used in `union`. This restriction has been removed in C++11.
Also you need to define a constructor if the union has member with non-trivial constructor.